# How to clear socket buffer to get the latest data from the latest request

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, pop3

I need to clear the socket buffer not to have all the socket "log" inside it. 
I have to work only with the latest response on my latest request.

I'm using a function to receive all data. 
I understand that I should somehow empty my socket buffer inside that function, but can't find a way I can do that.

```py
def recv_timeout(the_socket, timeout=2):
    # делаем сокет не блокируемым
    the_socket.setblocking(0)

    total_data = []
    data = ''

    begin = time.time()
    while 1:
        if total_data and time.time() - begin > timeout:
            break

        elif time.time() - begin > timeout * 2:
            break

        try:
            data = the_socket.recv(8192)
            if data:
                total_data.append(data)
                begin = time.time()
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)
        except:
            pass

    return b''.join(total_data)
```

When I send request like:

```py
client_socket.sendall('list\r\n'.encode("utf-8"))
```

I get a normal reply on my request.
But when I make

```py
client_socket.sendall('recv 1\r\n'.encode("utf-8"))
```

immediately after previous request, I get answer 1 + answer 2, but I need only answer 2.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TCP socket is a stream. All you can do is read everything that has already be received. That means that if your program is like

```
send req1
receive and process answer1
send req2
receive and process answer2
```

all should be fine.

But is you do:

```
send req1
send req2
```

then you will have to do

```
receive answer1
receive and process answer2
```